# MFMailComposeViewController Invalid Email Address?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email

I am using MFMailComposeViewController so the user can email in app. Just like so:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:emailString]];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

I have noticed if an invalid email address is given to it it simply doesn't put it into the recipients field, is there anyway of me taking action of this happens? Or overriding this?

Thanks.

Comment: what is there in your emailString ?

Comment: Lets say `emailString` equals `skdhfsf` then it detects its invalid and doesn't add it as a recipient, however lets say its `email@address.com`, its can see its valid and so adds it as a recipient. So is there anyway I can be told when it detects whether its valid or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to validate your email Address. Use this code below

```
    -(BOOL) NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
    {
          NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
          NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", stricterFilterString];
          return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
    }
```

Pass your email string as argument to NSStringIsValidEmail: method. It will return YES if valid, NO otherwise.

Comment: That regular expression will reject a lot of valid email addresses. The set of characters it allows before the "@" is way too small, and the assumption that the top-level domain is always 2-4 letters is incorrect too. See http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx